# How to update values of certain columns of a dataframe with values from another dataframe in r

Tags: r, dplyr

I am struggling to write an R code for the following problem:
df1 and df2 are two dataframes.

```
> df1 <- read.csv(file = 'Indx.csv')
> df1
  St_Name   I1   I2   I3   I4
1      TN 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25
2      AZ 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45
3      TX 0.50 0.55 0.60 0.65
4      KS 0.70 0.75 0.80 0.85
5      KY 0.90 0.95 0.11 0.12
6      MN 0.13 0.14 0.16 0.17
> df2 <- as.data.frame(fromJSON(file = "NewIndx.json"))
> df2
  St_Name  I1  I3
1      KS 100 200

# The output should be

> df1
  St_Name   I1   I2   I3   I4
1      TN 0.10 0.15 0.20 0.25
2      AZ 0.30 0.35 0.40 0.45
3      TX 0.50 0.55 0.60 0.65
4      KS  100 0.75  200 0.85
5      KY 0.90 0.95 0.11 0.12
6      MN 0.13 0.14 0.16 0.17
>
```

what is the optimal code to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You can have a look at the rows_update function from the tidyverse package.

Answer (score 0):

We could use this slightly modified function `coalesce_join` provided by Edward Visel:

```
library(tidyverse)
# the function:
coalesce_join <- function(x, y, 
                          by = NULL, suffix = c(".y", ".x"), 
                          join = dplyr::full_join, ...) {
  joined <- join(y, x, by = by, suffix = suffix, ...)
  # names of desired output
  cols <- union(names(y), names(x))
  
  to_coalesce <- names(joined)[!names(joined) %in% cols]
  suffix_used <- suffix[ifelse(endsWith(to_coalesce, suffix[1]), 1, 2)]
  # remove suffixes and deduplicate
  to_coalesce <- unique(substr(
    to_coalesce, 
    1, 
    nchar(to_coalesce) - nchar(suffix_used)
  ))
  
  coalesced <- purrr::map_dfc(to_coalesce, ~dplyr::coalesce(
    joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[1])]], 
    joined[[paste0(.x, suffix[2])]]
  ))
  names(coalesced) <- to_coalesce
  
  dplyr::bind_cols(joined, coalesced)[cols]
}

# apply 
coalesce_join(df1, df2, by = 'St_Name')
```

```
  St_Name     I1     I3   I2   I4
1      KS 100.00 200.00 0.75 0.85
2      TN   0.10   0.20 0.15 0.25
3      AZ   0.30   0.40 0.35 0.45
4      TX   0.50   0.60 0.55 0.65
5      KY   0.90   0.11 0.95 0.12
6      MN   0.13   0.16 0.14 0.17
```

Answer (score 0):

Kindly let me know if this is what you were anticipating.

```
library(tidyr)

id<- "St_Name"
df_1<- melt(df_1, id.vars = id, measure.vars = setdiff(colnames(df_1),id))
df_2 <- melt(df_2, id.vars = id, measure.vars = setdiff(colnames(df_2),id))
result <- merge(df_1,df_2, by=c("St_Name","variable"),no.dups = TRUE,all.x = TRUE)
result$value.x[which(!is.na(result$value.y))]<- result$value.y[which(!is.na(result$value.y))]
result <- result[,-4] 
result <-spread(result, variable, value.x)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use {powerjoin} and use the `conflict` argument. `coalesce_xy` will pick in priority data from the right side table.

**data**

```r
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~St_Name, ~I1,  ~I2, ~I3, ~I4,
  "TN", 0.10, 0.15, 0.20, 0.25,
  "AZ", 0.30, 0.35, 0.40, 0.45,
  "TX", 0.50, 0.55, 0.60, 0.65,
  "KS", 0.70, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85,
  "KY", 0.90, 0.95, 0.11, 0.12,
  "MN", 0.13, 0.14, 0.16, 0.17)

df2 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~St_Name, ~I1, ~I3,
  "KS", 100, 200
)
```

**solution**

```r
library(powerjoin)
power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "St_Name", conflict = coalesce_yx)
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   St_Name    I2    I4     I1     I3
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#> 1 TN       0.15  0.25   0.1    0.2 
#> 2 AZ       0.35  0.45   0.3    0.4 
#> 3 TX       0.55  0.65   0.5    0.6 
#> 4 KS       0.75  0.85 100    200   
#> 5 KY       0.95  0.12   0.9    0.11
#> 6 MN       0.14  0.17   0.13   0.16
```